# How to display two php arrays in one html table excluding the duplicates

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have two arrays in my php script, let's  suppose:

```
foreach( $orders_this_week as $this_week ){ 
    echo $this_week->day_of_week;
    echo $this_week->average_order;

    }
```

and the second one is

```
foreach( $orders_last_week as $last_week ){ 
    echo $last_week->day_of_week;
    echo $last_week->average_order;

    }
```

I want to display the above arrays result in 3 columns table, the first column will contain the day of the week, eg:

`$last_week->day_of_week` or `$this_week->day_of_week`

and will not be repeated, means if `$last_week->day_of_week` has sunday and also `$this_week->day_of_week` has sunday, then there will be one sunday in first column of HTML table.

In second column there will be `$this_week->average_order` corresponding to it's `$this_week->day_of_week`, and similarly in third column there will be `$last_week->average_order` corresponding to it's `$this_week->day_of_week`.

general example: let `$this_week` has `{[sunday, monday],[5,4]}`
and $`last_week` has {`[sunday, tuesday], [3,5]}`
so the output html table will be looking like

```html
<table border="1" width="300px">
  <tr>
 <th>Sunday</th>
 <td>5</td>
 <td>3</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
 <th>monday</th>
 <td>4</td>
 <td></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
 <th>tuesday</th>
 <td></td>
 <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array, indexed on day, and fill it with the correct values, then iterate the array to build you html table:

```
$days = [
    'Monday'=>[],
    'Tuesday'=>[],
    'Wednesday'=>[],
    //... rest of the days here
];
foreach( $orders_this_week as $this_week ){
    $days[$this_week->day_of_week]['this_week']=$this_week->average_order;
}

foreach( $orders_last_week as $last_week ){
    $days[$last_week->day_of_week]['last_week']=$last_week->average_order;
}
?>
<table>
    <?php foreach ($days as $day => $value): if(!empty($value)):?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $day;?></td>
            <td><?php echo isset($value['this_week'])?$value['this_week']:''?></td>
            <td><?php echo isset($value['last_week'])?$value['last_week']:''?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif; endforeach;?>
</table>
```

Comment: @SadamAfridi No problem, glad i could help